# How do i replace the phone gap spotlight icon for iOS7?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, cordova-3

Following [apple's instructions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html) on app icons doesn't show my image in the spotlight search.  The phonegap image shows for my app.  I have also tried replacing all of the phone gap images in finder with no luck.  I am using xCode 5.1 and PhongeGap 3.3 and an iOS7 iPad.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to image.xcassets and add your icons to the app icons section. The first icon should be 58x58, the second 80x80, and the third 120x120

Comment: This option doesn't work for me.  I tried it when I read apple's instructions, and I just tried it again.  However, I am just given 1x and 2x for 29pt, 40pt, and 76pt instead the dimensions you listed.

Comment: 29pt is 58x58, 40pt is 80x80, and 76pt is 120x120

Comment: This answer worked when I started using the iPad 4.  My problem only occurred on an old version of iPad.  Since 4 is the only model in production, I am good.  Thanks.